# Cognito Authorizer Test in console works, but Postman doesn't

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have setup API GW with Cognito user pool authorizer.
The token source is method.request.header.Authorization.
I get an ID token from a browser test app that I plug into the authorizer Test in the AWS console and I get HTTP 200. All is fine.

Now, when I use Postman to access the same resource with the

**Authorization**:(ID token) and

**Content-Type**:application/json headers,

I get a HTTP 401 response with the following headers:

*content-length →26*

*content-type →application/json*

*date →Wed, 27 Sep 2017 02:30:39 GMT*

*status →401*

*via →1.1 6eadd6c6c5a53c34c6fce458c34cd790.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)*

*x-amz-cf-id →0SE2SaWGwFLJvml_V-4ai3aBimAX8KKyjfWrrmHLugt9PaQVHRsI4Q==*

*x-amzn-errortype →UnauthorizedException*

*x-amzn-requestid →d9cfe16c-a32b-11e7-b1b9-1f4b319597f5*

*x-cache →Error from cloudfront*

I followed these [steps](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) (Call an API Integrated with a User Pool) but I can't really figure out what I am doing wrong...

Comment: what AWS region ?

Comment: Region is US-east-1

Comment: is that the cognito-request ID ? I did not find it in our logs

Comment: Not sure which one you are referring to. This is the only info I got from the API call. I can provide more info privately, but not sure how to reach you.

Comment: can you post your UserPoolId?

Comment: Otherwise cut a case with Cognito through your AWS Account.

Comment: us-east-1_5hx0t8Cv2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155462/discussion-between-vasileios-lekakis-and-breiz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after hours of googling and testing, I found out that in the APIG authorizer I had set up, the specified token source was:

*method.request.header.Authorization*

instead of simply

*Authorization*

The weird thing is that the authorizer test should fail too, if it truly mimicked the corresponding REST call.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, @Breiz is right. 
I used *Authorization* instead of *method.request.header.Authorization*.
Also, in Postman, I removed word *Bearer* along with space before the token and it worked.